# Django template, how to make a dropdown box with the predefined value selected?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to create a drop down list box with the selected value equal to a value passed from the template values, but with no success. Can anyone take a look and show me what I am doing wrong.

```
     <select name="movie">
       {% for movie in movies %}
    {% ifequal movie.id selected_movie.id %}
     <option value="{{movie.key}}" selected="true">Movie {{movie.id}}: {{movie.name}}</option>
     {% endifequal %}
     {% ifnotequal movie.id selected_movie.id %}
     <option value="{{movie.key}}">Movie {{movie.id}}: {{movie.name}}</option>
     {% endifnotequal %}
       {% endfor %}
     </select>
```

In this example, movies and selected_movie are passed from the template values.
Please advice!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code works for me with django 1.0.2 and firefox 3.5.

You can use {% else %} instead of {% ifnotequal %} and set selected="selected". Hope it helps.

```
<select name="movie">
    {% for movie in movies %}
        {% ifequal movie.id selected_movie.id %}
            <option value="{{movie.key}}" selected="selected">Movie {{movie.id}}: {{movie.name}}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{movie.key}}">Movie {{movie.id}}: {{movie.name}}</option>
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: You should inline the ifequal statement, so you only have one option tag. DRY. :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to get past a block.  Confirmed works with Django 2.0 and Firefox 57.0.4.