# Values of a dictionary in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, django, drop-down-menu, html-select

My models.py is as follows:

```
class SellerMarketplaces(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
seller_id = models.ForeignKey('Sellerdetails',db_column='Seller_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
mk_id = models.ForeignKey('Marketplace',db_column='Mk_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
username = models.CharField(db_column='Username', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have the following code in my views

```
def marketplaces(request):  
  seller = request.GET.get('seller', '')
  allmarketplaces = SellerMarketplaces.objects.filter(seller_id = seller).values('mk_id__marketplace')
  for i in range(len(allmarketplaces)):
    print allmarketplaces[i]['mk_id__marketplace']
  return render_to_response(request,'soumi1.html',{'marketplaces':marketplaces})
```

I am getting the values (Flipkart & Snapdeal) from the print allmarketplaces[i]['mk_id__marketplaces] line, but the return is giving me a 500 error.

My html file is:

```
        <select  name="marketplace" id="txtHint" size="1" required>
      <option value="">Select Marketplace</option>
        {% if marketplaces.count > 0 %}
          {% for marketplace in marketplaces %}
            <option value = {{ marketplace.id }}>{{ marketplace.marketplace }} </option>
          }
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

the javascript i used is:

```
  function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
   }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'/marketplaces?seller='+username['value']);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
```

Comment: 500 is a server side error, so something is going wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the trouble:

```
return render_to_response(request,'soumi1.html',{'marketplaces':marketplaces})
```

You are returning `marketplaces` but your view is also called `marketplaces`.

---

Taking a guess I'd say you want to return the list of marketplaces.

You can do that in the following way:

```
marketplaces_list = SellerMarketplaces.objects.filter(seller_id=seller).values_list('mk_id__marketplace', flat=True)

return render_to_response(request,'soumi1.html',{'marketplaces':marketplaces_list})
```

Comment: I changed the func name in the views and url to getmarketplaces, and when i run it, it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Add a `try ... except` block starting before `seller = ...` and ending after `return ...` to see what error you are actually getting.

Comment: yeah, u got me right! i want to return all the values in my dropdown as options, i tried assigning before, and with ur code,when I'm writing "print marketplaces_list" after the first line as well the line is throwing me an error.

Comment: with try..except I am getting "mk_id_marketplace (<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>)".. I donno how to solve it though..

Comment: See my [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32197276/3224008). Does this help? I thought the code you provided was working but I just realized you're getting a KeyError if `allmarketplaces` is empty.

Comment: when i am printing it with print allmarketplaces[i]['mk_id__marketplace'] it's showing me the results, yeah, ur answer gave me the values, but the return is my new problem now.

Comment: Replace `render_to_response` with `render` and see if the error persists.

Comment: Yeah.. It's still there

Comment: Then again put a `try ... except` block around `return ...`

Comment: ok.. considering i'm getting some values in my view like i said before, what command in "return ........" should i use in views.py to return the iterated values to my dropdown in html page? the dropdown has id=txtHint.

Comment: Depends on your template but in general you'd do this: `return render(request, 'template.html', {'marketplaces': marketplaces_list})` and in your template you can access the list with `{{ marketplaces_list }}`

Comment: but according to ur code, it's giving me a list [u'Flipkart', u'Snapdeal'].. how to i obtain a dropdown like 1) Flipkart                                                                2) Snapdeal

Comment: also now return isn't giving me any error but how do i find out if it's actually returning anything coz the  dropdown is getting blank and when i'm writing {{marketplaces_list}} somewhere on my template.html, it's not showing me the values as it's showing when i'm doing print marketplaces_list on views.py

Comment: Sorry, i meant `{{ marketplaces }}`, my bad. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1392747/3224008) how to create the dropdown in your template.